# Detect installed extension in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Goal: To detect if an extension is installed (from web-app JS not another extension) which has

1. No web_accessible_resources
2. No element added to DOM.

Most of the solutions on SO are related to checking one extension in another. But I want to check in website if user has an extension installed.

I have found a partial solution but that doesn't work as chrome cancels the API call if the content loaded is not accesible.

Here is the snippet attached:

```js
function detectExtensionUsingImage(extensionId, callback) {
        const img = new Image();
        const src = `chrome-extension://${extensionId}/resources/icon_16.png`;
        img.src = src;
        img.onload = function() {
            callback(true);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            callback(false);
        }
};

detectExtensionUsingImage('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', (isInstalled) => console.log(isInstalled ? 'Yay!' : 'Nay!'));


var detectExtensionUsingScript = function(extensionId, callbackFunc) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.onerror = () => callbackFunc(false);
    s.onload = () => callbackFunc(true)
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    const src = `chrome-extension://${extensionId}/manifest.json`;
    s.src = src;
}

detectExtensionUsingScript('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',(isInstalled) => console.log(isInstalled ? 'Yay!' : 'Nay!'));
```

[image: emphasized text]

Is there any other way to detect if an extension is installed (which uses popup and has no DOM elements added) with no web_accessible_resources?

P.S: I tried checking for the favicon/logo icon too but no success.

Comment: There's no way. If there would be one, it'd be a bug, which would be immediately fixed.

Comment: I understand that and could imagine how some malicious website could detect all the extensions installed information and exploit that information for nefarious purposes. 
On the other hand, if an extension is accessing/updating a website, in that case website should be able to detect what extension is that.

Comment: No, websites are not allowed to detect extensions that don't explicitly expose themselves, and this is intentional.